# Are there any examples of using Bring radicals to solve a quintic equation?

Tags: quintics

It says [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bring_radical) on Wikipedia that the general quintic equation can be solved if it is reduced to the principal quintic form, then to the Bring–Jerrard normal form. It gives a good overview and after reading it a few times, I feel I understand the general concept. However, it doesn't really give any specifics on how one would go about solving a quintic on their own. Are there any examples online of how to solve this?